# android home up icon is showing instead of action bar drawer toggle menu icon

Tags: android, actionbardrawertoggle

In my android app, I have navigation drawer and action bar drawer toggle icon with ic_menu icon which was working fine. Yesterday I added new dependency in my gradle file

compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

after added this, in main activity instead of ic_menu icon home up icon is appearing. If I click that it is working like drawer toggle. The only issue is icon.

Please help me to solve this issue.

find the below code which I used to initialize action bar drawer toggle

```
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, navDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

    };
    navDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Thanks,
Sundar

Comment: Try to remove  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: If I remove that then nothing shows there.. but I want navigation toggle icon

Comment: And when add: actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);